# Node js: Unexpected token '.' when trying to pass a global variable in curly braces

Tags: javascript

I am using the package [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to fetch pages from a website.

The website sets a new session cookie on every request so in order to stay logged in I need to use a cookie jar.

Here is the example for how to use a cookie jar from the got documentation:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const got = require('got');
const {CookieJar} = require('tough-cookie');

(async () => {
    const cookieJar = new CookieJar();
    const setCookie = promisify(cookieJar.setCookie.bind(cookieJar));

    await setCookie('foo=bar', 'https://example.com');
    await got('https://example.com', {cookieJar});
})();
```

In my case however, because the cookie gets reset after every request and requests can be made at any time from many different areas of my script I have defined my cookie jar as a global variable, like so: `global.cookieJar = new CookieJar();`.

However, I find myself unable to pass the global variable to the `got()` function. Got's documentation only shows passing the cookie jar to the `got()` function by placing it in curly brackets. Therefore, I should be able to pass the variable like: `await got('https://example.com', {global.cookieJar})`. But, if the variable in the curly brackets contains `.` () javascript throws an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` and does not allow the code to be executed.

How can I pass `global.cookieJar` to `got()` without causing a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
const foo = 1;
const object = { foo };
```

is shorthand for:

```
const foo = 1;
const object = { foo: foo };
```

There are two issues with:

```
{global.cookieJar}
```

- An identifier cannot have a `.` in it (hence your syntax error)
- The property name the function you are passing the object to is looking for is `cookieJar`, not `global.cookieJar`.

Don't use the shorthand.

```
{cookieJar: global.cookieJar}
```